# imagemagick: -gravity SouthEast -geometry offset did not work

Tags: macos, imagemagick

when replacing part of an image,

from

[image: 00]

to

[image: 11]

I replaced two parts of the image.

My solution is

[image: 33]

with `convert 1.png \( 1.png -crop 200x200+300+800 +repage \) -gravity SouthWest -geometry +0+0 -compose Copy -composite 2.png`,

I got

[image: 44]

with `convert 2.png \( 2.png -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage \) -gravity SouthEast -geometry -350-450 -compose Copy -composite 4.png`

I got the same image, what is wrong with me?

with `convert 2.png \( 2.png -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage \) -gravity Center -geometry +626+349 -compose Copy -composite 3.png`, got it .

not very familiar with the mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ImageMagick, in place of:

> convert 2.png ( 2.png -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage ) -gravity
>   SouthEast -geometry 0X0-350-450 -compose Copy -composite 4.png

Use:

```
convert 2.png \( +clone -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage \) -gravity SouthEast -geometry -350-450 -compose over -composite 4.png
```

Or:

```
convert 2.png \( +clone -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage \) -gravity center -geometry -350-450 -compose Copy -composite 4.png
```

That should make a difference. Do not add WxH (0x0) to your -geometry as that may try to make a W=0 and H=0 image, which will either fail or not show. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert

The +clone, just copies the previous image in the command line, which is 2.png. Repeating 2.png is OK, but will be slower as it has to read the 2.png image a second time.

Note, it is best not use images to show code. Just paste the code into the form and use the {} button to make it show in gray background.

Comment: Your tech tips are nice.

Comment: I tried your code. Not the way. My question is mainly on how to calculate the coordinates with `-gravity`. I spend a lot  of time to figure out the layout with `Center`. and tried a lot , not figuring out the intuitive layout with `SouthEast `

Comment: You were not that clear about that. You mainly said you could not get the command to show difference with different gravity settings. Please be more clear in the future about what your issue actually is.

Comment: seems like bottom left overlay of  bottom right corner

Comment: Using -gravity southeast and -geometry +0+0, the overlay will be positioned exactly in the southeast corner of the background image with the bottom right corner of the overlay aligned with the bottom right corner of the background image. Sorry, if I got that wrong above. I was thinking southeast but answered earlier with southwest. I have removed that post and reposted correctly below.

Comment: CORRECTED: Just to be more informative. For gravity=center, the offsets are center relative -- center of overlay relative to center of the background images. For gravity southeast, the offsets are bottom right of the overlay relative to bottom right of the background image. Similarly for the other gravity settings. So for gravity=southeast -geometry +0+0 would put the overlay image exactly in the bottom right corner of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

`convert 2.png \( +clone -crop 350x450+1252+200 +repage \) -gravity SouthEast -geometry +0+0 -compose over -composite 99.png`

experimented and figured out